# How to import a pem file directly to use with a FeignClient?

Tags: java, ssl, pem, feign

I have a client certificate .pem file including private key and certificate. I want to use Feign to call the restful api which requires client certificate.

I googled a lot of examples but those examples teach that import keys from jks like below:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
                .withIdentityMaterial("identity.jks", "password".toCharArray())
                .withTrustMaterial("truststore.jks", "password".toCharArray())
                .build();

        Feign.Builder client = Feign.builder()
                .client(new Client.Default(sslFactory.getSslSocketFactory(), sslFactory.getHostnameVerifier()));
    }

}
```

However, I want to import the cert from .pem file directly because I don't have .jks file and don't want convert it by manual because the .pem file is fetched programmatically periodically from other servers. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the library maintainer of the `SSLFactory` which you posted in your question. It is pretty easy to use pem files without converting them to keystore files. You need an extion library to enable that feature. Can you add the following library:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.hakky54</groupId>
    <artifactId>sslcontext-kickstart-for-pem</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

After importing the library you can use the following snippet

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager = PemUtils.loadIdentityMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/your/certificate-chain.pem"), Paths.get("/path/to/your/private-key.pem"));
        X509ExtendedTrustManager trustManager = PemUtils.loadTrustMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/your/some-trusted-certificate.pem"));

        SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
                  .withIdentityMaterial(keyManager)
                  .withTrustMaterial(trustManager)
                  .build();

        Feign.Builder client = Feign.builder()
                .client(new Client.Default(sslFactory.getSslSocketFactory(), sslFactory.getHostnameVerifier()));
    }

}
```

#### Update

It seems like the OP wants to supply a pem file as identity which contains the certificate chain and private key as a single file. On my initial answer I posted an example where two separate files need to be provided, but a single file is also possible, see here for the example:

```java
X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager = PemUtils.loadIdentityMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/your/identity.pem"));
```

If your private key is encrypted you can provide the password as second parameter as shown below:

```java
X509ExtendedKeyManager keyManager = PemUtils.loadIdentityMaterial(Paths.get("/path/to/your/identity.pem"), "password".toCharArray());
```

All possible usages can be found in the unit test of the PemUtils here:
https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart/blob/5bcc06a862d654e5e59daa4175c39abe230b8fb6/sslcontext-kickstart-for-pem/src/test/java/nl/altindag/ssl/util/PemUtilsShould.java#L65

Comment: thanks for your ans, but my pem file contains a private key and a client cert. PemUtils.loadIdentityMaterial() requires two separated pem files, one is key, one is cert. Can I only import one pem file which contains a key and a cert?

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully that is the answer you are looking for

Comment: wow, your library is so convenient. Thanks. It is what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi, I have trouble understanding one part of this, help would be appreciated: 
can I in this line .withTrustMaterial(trustManager) import the Root Certificate from a .pem bundle, so I don't need to import that Root cert to java keystore?

Comment: @MajaStamenic yes you can provide your own bundle to the permits which will give you a trust manager which you can use in the SSLFactory. There is no need for putting it into a keystore